# Zend DbTable add where in if() statement

Tags: zend-framework, where-clause, zend-db-table

I get my data by this way:

```
$table = new Application_Model_DbTable_FooBar();

$data = $table
->select()
->where('id = ?', (int) $id)
->query()
->fetchAll();
```

and want to add a separate where clause in an if() statement.
Something like that:

```
if($foo == "bar") {
    $data->where('foo = ?, 'bar');
}
```

So I tried something like that, but it didn't work.

```
$table = new Application_Model_DbTable_FooBar();

$table
->select()
->where('id = ?', (int) $id);

if($foo == "bar") {
    $table->where('foo = ?, 'bar');
}

$data = $table->query()->fetchAll();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$table = new Application_Model_DbTable_FooBar();

$table = $table
->select()
->where('id = ?', (int) $id);

if($foo == "bar") {
    $table = $table->where('foo = ?, 'bar');
}

$data = $table->query()->fetchAll();
```